Ways to improve Batch query performance with Spring Query
I have one objective, which is to get the minimum possible query time for the bulk insert of N number of records using standard Spring Data JPA using a remote Oracle database. I have tried few of the optimizations mentioned below but first, let me explain the scenario.
I have created a single-level entity (no associations) with 15 fields (mainly strings and longs with created and modified by dates). I am using a controller, which accepts a count (20K in this case) and it runs a simple method to instantiate 20K records using new Entity() and populate them with random data. Finally, used that entities repository's saveAll() method to save all the entities into the database. Now, the approaches that we have tried:

Standard way, no modification in above logic is taking around 40seconds
Added new field using Persistable interface which reduced select queries and few seconds in the process.
Added JPA's batch-inserts properties with 250 batch size, reduced to 33% of the time.
Increase batch size to 5K records in a batch which reduced to consistent 8-9 seconds.

What I have not tried yet is to use Spring batch as of now (which is in pipeline)?
Apart from this, I have ran out of the options to enhance the performance and not sure if it is practically possible to do so. (Not accounting the uncontrollables as of now like Network bandiwdth and all)
Is there any other way or configuration which we are missing out which could further enhance it?

Increasing the maximum-pool-size in your connection pool allows for more concurrent database connections. However, to take advantage of this, you need to ensure that your inserts are processed in multiple threads. By default, Spring Data JPA runs saveAll() in a single thread, using only one database connection at a time, regardless of the connection pool size.
